# Ext JS [Ext.net] GridPanel Pagination with Paging

Tags: extjs, ext.net

I have a `Ext.net` GridPanel Pagination with Paging  as:

```
<ext:PagingToolbar ID="PagingToolbar1" runat="server" PageSize="25" StoreID="GridStore" DisplayMsg="Displaying {0} - {1} of {2} Records" EmptyMsg="No data to display" HideRefresh="true"  >
</ext:PagingToolbar>
```

My Problem is that Initially when the `Grid Panel` is loaded ... in the first page all the **binded** data in the `Grid Store` is displayed .. after browse though pages pagination shows correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution by Providing the Following code in `C#`

```
  PagingToolbar1.PageSize = 25;
  PagingToolbar1.PageIndex = 1;
```